# Why do I have this weird shading issue?

Tags: modeling, shaders, topology, shadows, knife-tool

I'm modelling a Gameboy right now and after adding the dpad und an A button. After remeshing everything into quads I still have some harsh edges around the A button and I cannot figure out why.

I have enabled auto smoothing but that doesnt help anymore. I set the main object to shade smooth, but I dont know how shade this completely clean.

the added blend file
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: hey i just added it to the question

Comment: BTW this looks far out of proportion to a real GameBoy, so if you're looking to model an accurate GameBoy, set a picture of one as your background and make your model match up.

Comment: yeah thats supposed to be like it :D i want to have a gameboy in emoji style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shades smooth between the front and side faces. Put the *Weighted Normal* below the *Bevel* modifier and it will fix the problem as it will take the virtual bevel faces into account:

[image]

Comment: damn man thanks now its shaded very clean!!! Thank u

Comment: what would you say about the topology mesh ? good or bad ?

Comment: You could have made it simpler (for example less vertices for the cylindric hole and give your object a Subdivision Surface to make it rounder)